# Remove plot from matplotlib subplot, but keep legend visible

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a very customized subplot set up.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=2, ncols=2, width_ratios=[3, 1])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 0])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1, -1])
ax4=fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
```

This sets up 3 slots for plotting: one that takes up half the space on the left, and two smaller ones on the right. However, I only want the bottom right to actually be a plot. I want the top right to be the space where the legend for the larger plot on the left to go. I could just use the axes from `ax` to do this, but that shifts the whole plotting space off. Instead I thought of trying to just create `ax4` and place the `ax` legend there.

```
lines = []
labels = []

for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ln, la = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    lines.extend(ln)
    labels.extend(la)
legend = ax4.legend(lines, labels, labelspacing=0.1, loc=(-0.3,0.6), fontsize='xx-large')
fig.tight_layout()
```

This puts the legend exactly where I want it, but the blank figure shows up, which I don't want. Is it possible to accomplish what I want using this method? If not, what is my alternative? Picture below to better understand.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ax4.axis('off')` to make axis 4 invisible if you want to stick to your approach.
However, I don't see why you don't just skip creating axis 4 and just use `fig.legend()` instead of `ax.legend()`. Then the legend is placed outside the axis and you can then control the exact position just as you already did with the `loc` keyword.

Comment: Very good point. For some reason I didn't think of adding the legend to the fig instead of a specific axis. Accepting your response though as it does work as intended.